# Check for NULLs in a View generically in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

How to check for null values in a table or more precisely in the view? because underlying tables might have NULLs but that is handled in the view definition. The catch here is that there are around hundred columns, so there is no way to do that manually column by column or in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific function that receives all the fields in the row as input and checks if one of them is null by returning 1.
Once you have done this function just add it in the query of the view passing the fields and putting in where the flag = 1.
This way you will only extract the rows where one of the fields is null. If you want to have fun you could also return to the output of the aforementioned function the name of the field o fields that are null (possibly concatenated) so you know immediately where to look.
Good luck!